# Wait and Notify not behaving as expected , thread is getting hanged

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is the code sample: Thread is getting hanged after consuming 5 or 6 values
I do not know where i am missing anything.And one more doubt that i Had was regarding calling the constructor of the MyIncrementor class. Initially I was trying to call the get and set in Producer and Consumer Class by creating new object of the MyIncrementor class, it was not working too

```
/**
 * 
 */
package multithreadingDemo;

/**
 * @author Aquib
 *
 */
public class ThreadCommDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyIncrementor mi=new MyIncrementor();
        Producer1 p=new Producer1(mi);
        Consumerrs c=new Consumerrs(mi);
        Thread t1=new Thread(p);
        Thread t2=new Thread(c);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();


    }

}



class MyIncrementor {
    int myCount;
    boolean valueSet;

    /**
     * @return the myCount
     */
    public synchronized int getMyCount() {
        if (!valueSet) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("get" + myCount);
        valueSet = true;
        notifyAll();
        return myCount;
    }

    /**
     * @param myCount
     *            the myCount to set
     */
    public synchronized void setMyCount(int myCount) {
        if (valueSet) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Set" + myCount);
        this.myCount = myCount;
        valueSet = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

}

class Producer1 implements Runnable {
    MyIncrementor mi;

    public Producer1(MyIncrementor mi) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mi=mi;
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            mi.setMyCount(i);
            System.out.println("Produced" + mi.myCount);
             try 
             {
                   Thread.currentThread().sleep((int)(Math.random() * 100));
             } 
             catch (InterruptedException ie) 
             {
                   ie.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    }
}

class Consumerrs implements Runnable {
    MyIncrementor mi;

    public Consumerrs(MyIncrementor mi) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mi=mi;
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            int val = mi.getMyCount();
            System.out.println("Consumed" + val);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have logical mistakes in your `MyIncrementor` class, you are setting `valueSet` incorrectly, so you have to either change your conditions or set the flag vice versa in `getMyCount` and `setMyCount` methods.

So, here is the corrected version of `MyIncrementor`:

```
class MyIncrementor {
  int myCount;
  boolean valueSet = false; //line changed - just to show that by default it is initialized to false

  /**
   * @return the myCount
   */
  public synchronized int getMyCount() {
    while (!valueSet) { //corrected as advised in comments, see @Tom Hawtin - tackline answer for details
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("get" + myCount);
    valueSet = false; //line changed - after getting the value set flag to false
    notifyAll();
    return myCount;
  }

  /**
   * @param myCount
   *            the myCount to set
   */
  public synchronized void setMyCount(int myCount) {
    while (valueSet) { //corrected as advised in comments, see @Tom Hawtin - tackline answer for details
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Set" + myCount);
    this.myCount = myCount;
    valueSet = true; //line changed - after setting the value set flag to true
    notifyAll();
  }

}
```

Comment: This answer would be considerably more useful if you would explain what you changed and why.

Comment: Ok, added comments. Look for `//line changed` comments in the code. Not sure how to explain it in more details, since it is just a logical mistake.

Comment: See Hawtin’s answer for the right way to use wait. Failing to point that out makes this incorrect, downvoted.

Comment: @NathanHughes Corrected the code, though in common using `while` with `wait()` is the right way of doing things, in this particular case it doesn't cause the issue.

Comment: Yes, that is true. For the case of 2 threads it doesn’t. But it’s a pretty lame program that relies on this in order to work.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that stands out is the lack of a `while`.

```
    if (valueSet) { // <-- if is wrong
        try {
            wait();
```

`wait` should be in a `while`. This ensures that the condition is met, rather than waking up for some other reason or no reason at all.

```
    while (valueSet) {
        try {
            wait();
```

Presumably the problem is that you have your flag the wrong way around.

```
    if (!valueSet) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    valueSet = true;
```

Presumably the `if` (should be a `while`) is intended that `valueSet` is `true`, but then you overwrite `true` with `true` rather than modifying the variable.

Also of not, `Thread.sleep` is a static method. It is incredibly misleading (though a common mistake) to call it on an instance.

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(/* ... */); // misleading
```

should be

```
Thread.sleep(/* ... */);
```